# Как найти базовый адрес?

Tags: c++

как мне найти базовый адрес указателя вида "server.dll"+0066CAA ?
[image: адрес]

Как найти адрес "server.dll" в приложении?

Comment: Приложение стороннее? Уточните данный факт..

Answer (score 1):

`server.dll` — Это адрес загруженного модуля, т.е. `HMODULE`/`HINSTNACE` или же просто `void*`.

[GetModuleHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199(v=vs.85).aspx) вернет вам адрес загруженного модуля *если он уже загружен*.

То что у вас идет после `server.dll`, это отступ от адреса модуля, что бы узнать этот адрес, вам необходимо применить арифметику к указателю на начальный адрес модуля, в вашем случае прибавить к данному адресу значение `0066CAA` *(имейте ввиду, это число представлено в виде `hex` а полный адрес будет выглядеть так: `0x0066CAA` = `421034`)*.

В итоге имеем следующий код:

```
HMODULE server_module = GetModuleHandle("server.dll");
char* address_with_offset = ((char*)server_module) + 0x0066CAA;
```

Comment: Только адресная арифметика с `void*` запрещена

Comment: @int3: Ну это уже зависит от того какой тип указателя необходим TS. `void*` привел как пример.

Comment: Мы отсчитываем байты, поэтому нужен `(char*)server_module`.

Comment: @LLENN Только пример с `void*` не является валидным кодом с точки зрения стандарта

Comment: Спасибо,но GetModuleHandle("server.dll") возвращает 0.

Comment: @AtmPok: Как вы его вызываете, и откуда? Т.к. если вы это производите из стороннего приложения, и у вас не загружен модуль с именем `server.dll`, то он однозначно вернет вам 0.